# How to mark function argument as output

Tags: c++, c, gcc, attributes, out

C# allows to mark function argument as output only:

```
void func(out int i)
{
    i = 44;
}
```

Is it possible to do something similar in C/C++? This could improve optimization. Additionally is should silence out warnings "error: 'myVar' may be used uninitialized in this function", when variable is not initialized and then passed to function as output argument.

I use gcc/g++ (currently 4.4.7) to compile my code.

**Edit:** I know about pointers and references, this is not what I am looking for. I need something like this:

```
void func(int* __attribute__((out)) i)
{
    *i = 44;
}

void func2()
{
    int myVal; // gcc will print warning: 'myVar' may be used uninitialized in this function
    func(&myVal);
    //...
}
```

**Edit 2:** Some extra code is needed to reproduce warning "'myVar' may be used uninitialized in this function". Additionally you have to pass -Wall -O1 to gcc.

```
void __attribute__((const)) func(int* i)
{
    *i = 44;
}

int func2()
{
    int myVal; // warning here
    func(&myVal);
    return myVal;
}
```

Comment: Do you want pointers? Like `void func(int* i){*i = 44;}` (C)?

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. In C++ you should use references, in C you only have pointers.

Comment: I need additional attribute to mark ptr/ref argument as out only. I updated my question to state this.

Comment: My g++ [does not warn anything](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/e813548cc65d4546) even with `-Wall -Wextra -pedantic` flags and even if `myVal` is used in `func2`. I'm assuming that you meant to pass the address of `myVal` into `func`.

Comment: Please see my edit 2, some extra code plus -O1 was needed.

Comment: Just out of pure curiosity, why do you need this ?

Comment: Having lied to the compiler with `__attribute__((const))`, which promises that the function ["does not examine any values except its arguments, and has no effects except the return value"](https://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Common-Function-Attributes.html), you now complain that the compiler is fooled by the lie?

Comment: I think pointers are the only option for this in C/C++.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

> *"Is it possible to do something similar in C/C++?"*

Not really. Standard c++ or c doesn't support such thing like a output only parameter.

In c++ you can use a reference parameter to get in/out semantics:

```
void func(int& i) {
          // ^
    i = 44;
}
```

For c you need a pointer, to do the same:

```
void func(int* i) {
          // ^ 
    *i = 44;
 // ^
}
```

---

Note that there are no distinctions between `out` and `in&out` parameters, unless you use a `const` reference (which means input only):

```
void func(const int& i) {
       // ^^^^^
    i = 44;
}
```

Comment: Note that there are no distinctions between `out` and `in&out` parameters.

Comment: Unless you use `const` as explained in another answer ;)

Comment: I need additional attribute to mark ptr/ref argument as out only. I updated my question to state this.

Comment: @DanielFrużyński _"I need additional attribute to mark ptr/ref argument as out only."_ You simply cannot in standard c++ or c.

Comment: I know this, and I am looking for some non-standard, probably gcc-only extension.

Comment: @DanielFrużyński _"I am looking for some non-standard, probably gcc-only extension"_ Not that I'm aware of one. I'd say that the semantics as defined in the language standards for c++ or c, inherently won't allow such extension being implemented.

Comment: gcc already implements additional attributes for functions, variables and types. Attribute for function argument could look like this: `void func(int* __attribute__((out)) i)` or `void func(__attribute__((out)) int* i)`

Comment: it's such a pity C++ doesn't have an `out` designation, because sometimes that it the pattern and it would be super nice if the compile gave you similar warning as what you get in C# eg when you forget to set the value.

Answer (score 2):

When you want to pass an arg as output in C++ you pass it as a reference :

```
 void func(int &i)
{
    i = 44;
}
```

and you **must** initialize it before doing anything on it.

*Note* :
You can specify when you want the arg to be just an **input** with a const ref :

```
 void func(const int &i)
{
    i = 44;
}
```

Comment: I need additional attribute to mark ptr/ref argument as out only. I updated my question to state this.

Comment: You just can't, you can just specify an input only, not an output only

Answer (score 0):

As others have noted, you can use a pointer or reference to pass out parameters. But there is no way to annotate whether it is **in**, **out**, or **in/out**.

```
void func(int &i); // Out or in/out. Non-nullable.
void func(int *i); // Out or in/out. Nullable.
void func(const int &i); // In. Non-nullable.
void func(const int *i); // In. Nullable.
```

**Microsoft Compiler Extension**

If using MSVC, The Microsoft [Source-code Annotation Language (SAL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/code-quality/understanding-sal?view=msvc-170) can provide such annotation and perform compile-time static analysis to enforce the correct usage on the caller.

```
void func(_Out_ int &i);
void func(_Out_ int *i);
void func(_Out_opt_ int *i);
void func(_Inout_ int &i);
void func(_Inout_ int *i);
void func(_Inout_opt_ int *i);
void func(_In_ const int &i);
void func(_In_ const int *i);
void func(_In_opt_ const int *i);
```